# How to stop a random number generator from generating duplicate numbers in ABAP

Tags: random, abap

So I have cobbled together a random number generator for a study project. what it does is generating a random number and then generating more random numbers based on the value of the first number.

It works fine so far the only thing I need it to stop doing is generating the same number twice.

```
DATA :
  lv_MinI  TYPE i VALUE 2,
  lv_MaxI  TYPE i VALUE 6,
  lv_RndI  TYPE i,
  lv_RndII TYPE i,
  lv_i     TYPE i VALUE 10.


DO 1 TIMES.

  CALL FUNCTION 'QF05_RANDOM_INTEGER'
    EXPORTING
      ran_int_max = lv_MaxI
      ran_int_min = lv_MinI
    IMPORTING
      ran_int     = lv_RndI.
  WRITE: / lv_RndI.
  ULINE.
  DO lv_RndI TIMES.
    CALL FUNCTION 'QF05_RANDOM_INTEGER'
      EXPORTING
        ran_int_max = lv_MaxI
        ran_int_min = lv_MinI
      IMPORTING
        ran_int     = lv_RndII.
    WRITE: / lv_RndII.
  ENDDO.
ENDDO.
```

Here is the output:

```
5
4
6
4
3
4
```

How would I stop generating the number 4 three times over?

Comment: By the way: The recommended way to generate random numbers is the class `cl_abap_random`.

Answer (score 6):

A standard pseudorandom number generator is designed to appear as if it wasn't biased by previous events. Which means it will occasionally output repeated numbers. Just like it's possible for a die to turn up with the same number twice in a row.

If you don't want repeated numbers, then you shouldn't roll dice, you should deal cards.

What I mean with that is to build a shuffle bag.

1. Put all the possible values into an internal table `lt_shufflebag`
2. Draw values by generating a random number `lv_rand` between 1 and `lines( lt_shufflebag )` and then using `READ TABLE lt_shufflebag INDEX lv_rand` to obtain the value in that table row
3. Delete that table row with `DELETE TABLE lt_shufflebag INDEX lv_rand` to remove the row you just read (the rows after that row will move down, so the table ends up with one row less).
4. Don't forget to handle the case that the table is empty because you used up all the entries. You probably want to re-generate the table in that case.

Comment: plus 1 for the free probability lesson and the preferred library.